# What is Youtube's thresholds regarding server error 402 payment required (excessive requests)?

Tags: youtube-api

Just that, would like to know this, been searching around but can't find any concrete numbers. Note, I'm referring to standard page requests to youtube pages, not API usage.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The free quota is

50,000,000 units/day

3000 requests/second/user

https://console.developers.google.com/project/[PROJECTNAME]/apiui/apiview/youtube?tabId=quotas

Comment: Thanks. However, I'm looking for thresholds regarding normal  page requests, not API requests. I've edited the question to be clearer about that. Thanks.